# Use of metaclass python to override __init__ and instantiate the class later on

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x

I m writting some API which would use configuration-like arguments.

Here is an example configuration which will be used by my API

```
quail.run(
    quail.SolutionPacked(path='Allum1'),
    quail.Installer(
        name='Allum1',
        icon='icon.jpeg',
        binary='allum1',
        console=True
    ),
    quail.builder.Builder(
        quail.builder.CmdIcon('icon.ico'),
        quail.builder.CmdZip(solution_path, 'solution.zip')
    )
)
```

The only problem with that: we will always instantiate, even when we won't use the instance, (for example if we want to uninstall we won't use the install class)

One way around I have found is to use metaclass and override `__call__` to get an "EggInstance" so I can instantiate the actual class later on.

Example implementation:

```
import six

class InstanceEgg:
    def __init__(self, cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self._cls = cls
        self._args = args
        self._kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self):
        return self._cls(_get_instance=True, *self._args, **self._kwargs)

class Egg(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        get_instance = kwargs.pop("_get_instance", False)
        if get_instance:
            return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return InstanceEgg(cls, *args, **kwargs)

@six.add_metaclass(Egg)
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        print("init %d %d" % (a, b))
```

Example use:

```
egg = Test(1, 2)
print("got egg")
f = egg()
```

Output:

```
got egg
init 1 2
```

Do you think it is acceptable to use metaclass for this purpose?

And what do you recommend?

Comment: What's the difference between instantiating an object and instantiating a factory? It's hard to advise you on whether this is appropriate, when we don't know what the constructors for these `quail` objects look like, and what the objects do.

Comment: Installer class will be used to install a solution with install() method and others. Solution class will be used to retrieve a solution (download or unzip) with  open() retrieve() and close()
Which means we are already initializing stuff in the constructor: like where will be the install folder. if you want more informations, here is the project https://github.com/mouuff/Quail

Comment: Also I forgot to mention, this classes could possibily be inherited by the "user developer" to change the default behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it you have objects that you only want to *partially* create, when you create them the first time.

To do this you can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
quail.run(
    partial(quail.SolutionPacked, path='Allum1'),
    partial(
        quail.Installer,
        name='Allum1',
        icon='icon.jpeg',
        binary='allum1',
        console=True
    ),
    partial(
        quail.builder.Builder,
        partial(quail.builder.CmdIcon, 'icon.ico'),
        partial(quail.builder.CmdZip, solution_path, 'solution.zip')
    )
)
```

Yeah, this isn't really that attractive. However it *is* what you want.

And so you can use a metaclass to perform this action automagically.
I'd remove the `_get_instance` stuff from your `Egg`, remove `InstanceEgg` and use a `partial` call.

```
from functools import partial


class PartialInit(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return partial(super().__call__, *args, **kwargs)


@six.add_metaclass(PartialInit)
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        print('init {} {}'.format(a, b))


t = Test('a')
print('Made t: {}'.format(t))
t('b')
```

Comment: I didn't know about functools.partial
but this solution forces to write additionnal stuff while writting configuration and stilll keeping metaclass's magic stuff, I don't see the advantage

Comment: @mou "forces to write additionnal stuff while writting configuration". How and where does it do this?

Comment: Writting partial() every time passing a class

Comment: @mou You don't have to do that... As I said that's what you'd do _without_ a metaclass, and so "you can use a metaclass to perform this action automagically"